# AppBarButton in compact mode inside CommandBar

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-universal

I found in the documentation for CommandBar this description:

> The app bar button controls are characterized by an icon and associated label. They have two sizes; normal and compact. By default, the text label is shown. When the IsCompact property is set to true, the text label is hidden. **When used in a CommandBar control, the CommandBar sets the IsCompact property automatically as the control is opened and closed.**

Am I able to somehow keep `IsCompact` mode active for `AppBarButton` also if a `CommandBar` is opened?

It works if I use `AppBar`, however, it does not have `SecondaryCommands` and also I can see in the documentation some kind of recommendation to use CommandBar instead of AppBar for Windows 10 apps.

> You should use the `AppBar` only when you are upgrading a Universal Windows 8 app that uses the `AppBar`, and need to minimize changes. For new apps in Windows 10, we recommend using the `CommandBar` control instead.

I was experimenting with `Opening` and `Opened` events of `CommandBar` but I was not too much successful with any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the AppBarButton template (fou can find it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299122.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), and remove the changes in the compact visualstate.

This way they'll always look the same.

Comment: Ah, I just did not realize this simple approach. Thanks a lot.